# My Nexus 4 says it's charging but it's actually discharging

Tags: 4.2-jelly-bean, charging, nexus-4

I plug in my Nexus 4 to a charger cable plugged into a wall outlet each night, and each morning I disconnect it.

But sometimes during the day when it's *not* plugged in, like today, it says "Charging - 95%", and later, it says, "Charging - 92%", and continues to discharge normally. The battery icon also shows the little lightning bolt symbol to indicate charging.

I've seen the related/similar questions but they don't match my device or situation, as far as I can tell. Since other devices have similar issues, is it a software problem?

Comment: What happens if you restart your phone?

Comment: @TronicZomB That seems to work. Also, a few hours later, it seemed to have changed to the normal "discharging" status.

Comment: Next time this happens, go to Settings => Battery and check what app is consuming your power. Normally it should be `screen 70%`.

Comment: is the charger cable the one that came with your device? did you flash anything into the device? have you tried calibrating the battery?

Comment: @svarog Yes, no, no. For the record, I haven't seen this behavior lately... it may come up again, as it does, but we'll see.

Comment: i am experiencing the same problem, the phone is running Android 4.3 and the charger is the [MC-02A](http://www.aliexpress.com/item/Qi-Standard-USB-Port-Wireless-Charger-for-Samsung-Galaxy-S4-Nokia-Lumia-920-820-LG-Nexus/1117450894.html)

Comment: I have the same problem. Rebooting the phone clears the condition but the same thing happens the next day. Factory resetting the phone (any phone) is always a pain. I will consider it for the sake of seeing what happens but now that the Moto X is available and a Nexus 5 is around the corner I'll probably just upgrade my phone. I do not have time for this kind of operation. This phone is only six months old and is my second Nexus 4!

Answer (score 1):

Either the battery is damaged or it's a software issue. You should first try to reboot the phone. If it doesn't fix it, try a factory reset.

Answer (score 0):

This happens to me too. But only when leaving the screen on with full brightness, having a wifi hotspot, using location services, and playing a game at the same time. Basically, you are using more power than your charger can provide.

Answer (score -1):

It wasn't really a new question. It's the same as this one but with all the mentioned precautions already in place. Plus a full power off would preclude apps from preventing a battery charge since it's not idle but off. So my contention is that these temp fixes seem t circumvent a major flaw in the system but nothing actually seems to permanently fix it. The comment is on topic it just expands the parameters a bit since we're not all experiencing the same results from many different fixes. From what I am seeing most of these fixes are temporary and don't actually fix anything they are workarounds that must be repeated often.

Comment: To me, this content looks like a mix of commentary and a possible answer (needs sources to back it up).